# Multivariable fractional calculus

Tags: fractional-calculus

I recently started to learn about nonlocal PDEs. Sorry if I am missing something really standard in this field.

I know Riesz derivative is defined through Fourier transform:

$$\mathcal{F}(\partial^\alpha u/\partial|x|^\alpha)(k)=|k|^\alpha\mathcal{F}(u)(k).$$

Within the standard calculus on $\mathbb{R}^n$, if function is defined on $n$-dimensional domain, say $u\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$, then $\nabla u\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n;\mathbb{R}^n)$, $\nabla^2u\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n;\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^n)$ and so on.

My question is that, how do we interpret this in fractional calculus (especially in Riesz type)? For example, is it possible to talk about "the direction" of $D^su$ for $s\in(0,1)$, whatever the notion of "direction" that coincides with $Du$ when $s=1$?

Sorry for my ignorance, and thank you in advance.